# How in ORACLE CRMOD will a field becomes read only when the pick-list is set to some value

Tags: oracle, readonly, siebel, ondemand

In Oracle **CRM ON DEMAND** we have the “Status” dropdown  field with value as “Completed” in Activities. I have Configure it in a such a way so that the **Subject** field becomes **read only** when the **status** is set to **Completed**.How to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer its by using Field Validation by writing Expression.To make Subject Field Read-Only when Status is set to Completed, follow these steps:

- GOTO.Admin>Application **Customisation>Activity>Activity Field Set UP**.
- Click Subject and in Field Validation box,
- write the following expression

  - **PRE('') = [] OR NOT []=LookupValue("EVENT_STATUS", "Completed")**
- save it to see required result

Comment: PRE('<Subject>') = [<Subject>] OR NOT [<Status>]=LookupValue("EVENT_STATUS", "Completed")